# POST with Jquery and receive a response from Node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to do something very simple, I want to do a POST with AJAX Jquery to a Node.js server and have the server return a response. My problem is that I can't get that answer from the server. If someone can help me, I will be very grateful.

client.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $.post("http://localhost:3333/vrp",
    {
      name: "Donald Duck",
      city: "Duckburg"
    },
    function(data,status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status); //This section code doesn't execute.
    })
    .fail(function() {
       alert( "error" );       //It's executed this section of code and I can see it in my browser.
    });
});
});
```

server.js

```
var vrp = require("./vrp");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/vrp', function(req, res){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));   //Here I can see the message I sent.
  res.contentType('json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body));
});

var listener = app.listen(3333, function () {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + 
  listener.address().port);
});
```

Comment: What error message do you get - please check your browsers dev tools? It might be a CORS related problem...

Comment: Have you tried with `contentType('jsonp')` ?

Comment: and probably you don't need this: `res.contentType('json'); res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body));` it `res.send(req.body);` should be enought

Comment: I'm going to try the solution that @Oliver told me, the other people's solutions didn't work (I think because maybe it's a configuration problem). How can I see the error message of the response? Sorry for the question, I'm a beginner in this area, and I don't have much idea.

Comment: Look to my answer, it has some ready to test / ready to use code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in server.js add CORS header, eg. like this

```
app.post('/vrp', function(req, res){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").send(req.body);
});
```

If this run, then you have 100% sure that was CORS problem.
For real app you can use this solution or more complex like middleware, eg.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Or you can use cors middleware module https://github.com/expressjs/cors with more elastic configuration.

Comment: Yes!! It worked! thanks so much! I have to learn about it, regards!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/vrp', function(req, res){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  return res.status(200).send({data:req.body});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest way to do this with Node.js LTS version 16.13.1

Simply install cors middleware module:

```
npm install --save cors
```

And use it in your post route like this:

```
// Other parts of your code
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');

// app.use(cors()); // if you want cors to be used for all routes

app.post('/vrp', cors(), (req, res) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

Pretty neat :).

If you use `app.use(cors())`, then you don't have to include the middleware as a parameter in individual routes; the middleware will be used for all routes