# How to get alert in nodejs using jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, forms, response

I'm trying to create a function in javascript that gives an alert if the posted data in a form is good or wrong, I'm using Jquery and nodejs

there is my function from clientside.

```
function myFunction() {
console.log('hellooooo');
$('#select_link').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
console.log('select_link clicked');
var value = document.getElementById(secretnumber); 
$.ajax({
  url: "/testValue", // La ressource ciblée
  type: "POST",
  data: value,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(returns) {
    console.log('Data received : ' + returns);
    if (returns) {
      alert("Correct number");
    } else {
      alert("Wrong number");
    }
  }
});

 });

}
```

And this is my form in html

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
 <input type="text" name="number" id="secretnumber">
 <input type="submit" value="Testear" id="select_link">
</form>
```

And this is my server function

```
app.post('/testValue',(req,res)=>{
console.log('Received data in server :' + req.body);
//res.send(req.body);
if(req.body.value ==='4')
{
    res.send('true');
}else{
    res.send('false');
}
});
```

Excuse me, but I'm a little lost on that code, thanks so much for your help

Comment: Could you explain what part of your code is not working like you expect it to?

Comment: check this [POST with Jquery and receive a response from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339446/post-with-jquery-and-receive-a-response-from-node-js)

Comment: Jakub , the part that is not working is the one where I try to print data received in server side, also I can't even print the message in console.log('select_link clicked');